# Best way to implement design with several DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been asked to create a menu that looks like the attached.

Essentially the colored rectangles are buttons which will expand and collapse when hovered over.

My plan is to generate 225 rectangular div elements using javascript and a loop.  For the buttons, instead of creating a div, i'll create a button.

Unfortunately this will mean that I will have 200 DOM elements that aren't really doing anything.  Seems like a waste.

Any tips on how to implement this design?

[Menu Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImHNo.png)

Comment: Try an SVG instead.

Comment: This may be a valid use case for [client side imagemaps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp), careful though, this is old technology and hipsters may laugh at you

Comment: You could floating links over an image, but SVG is definitely an option.  Or just go for it as you described-- not like you've got a finite amount of `div`s to work with :)

Comment: @JSelser -- if you're thinking of using an imagemap, you might as well just do absolutely positioned links over an image-- simpler syntax, easier to manage (imho)

Comment: @anied unless you can somehow specify the mappings relatively. Anything absolutely positioned like that is shit, so its worth looking it up

Comment: Meh, with all the extra effects in his requirements, honestly both the absolutely position links and image maps are probably bad solutions-- better to just look for an SVG way to do it as recommended by Bergi.  There's some libraries out there that could help you.